# Email template banner image dimension

Tags: html, css, email-attachments, email-templates

I am email template designed which contains a Banner Image. Everything is aligned perfectly except the banner. Below is my code snippet and output what I am receiving.

```html
<p><img src="medical.jpg" width="100%" height="144" /></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 300;">Hello</span></span>
  </span>
</p>
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="height: 40px;" colspan="5">
        <p><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 300;">You Project(${URI_REF}) has been submitted and is being reviewed by&nbsp;<strong>${u_project_manager}</strong>.</span></span>
        </p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: #e6e7e8; color: #396b53;" colspan="5"><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 500;"><strong>Title</strong></span></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="color: black;" colspan="5"><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 300;">${short_description}</span></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: #e6e7e8; color: #396b53;" colspan="3"><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 500;"><strong>Submitted by</strong></span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="background-color: #e6e7e8; color: #396b53;" colspan="1"><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 500;"><strong>Approver</strong></span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="background-color: #e6e7e8; color: #396b53;" colspan="1"><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 500;"><strong>Department</strong></span></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="color: black;" colspan="3"><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 300;">${submitter}</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="color: black;" colspan="1"><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 300;">${u_project_manager}</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="color: black;" colspan="1"><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 300;">${department}</span></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<hr />
<p><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 500;">Thank you,<br /></span><span style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;">IT Service Desk</span></span>
</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Output:
In my Gmail it is working perfectly fine but when it comes to outlook it is not working fine

Output:

Gmail Output
[image]

Outlook Output
[image]

[image: Updated Banner outlook]

In the Outlook the complete page itself displays the banner but in gmail it looks Okay. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Try placing the code for the image banner and welcome text inside of the main `table` container

Comment: You mean after <tbody> tag ???

Comment: Yes, after that; and use `tr` for each row, instead of the `div` tag

Comment: It didnt worked Matt :(

Answer (score 1):

Remove the height and change the width of 100% for the image to the width of your email.

Example:

```
<p><img src="medical.jpg" width="100%" height="144" /></p>
```

should be:

```
<p><img src="medical.jpg" width="600" /></p>
```

The width of `600 pixels` will be the width of your email. Height attribute can be dropped because if you assign a width to an image, height is proportionate. Don't use width in style tag, Outlook ignores it.

Also by default if you are using retina images (or really big ones) Outlook will resize the image to its original dimensions if it does not find a width attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try using height property in percent, something like 35% or use 144px

```
<img src="medical.jpg" width="100%" height="144px" />
```

or

```
<img src="medical.jpg" width="100%" height="35%" />
```

Comment: Let me try Ajay. But for it looks Width is working perfectly fine but the problem is with the height.

Comment: Yes, you should remove the height which is affecting the ratio. But however you are not getting full width on outlook. For that you can try using it in style property.

Comment: Not Working Ajay. Width is getting cut to half of the screen

Comment: Sorry about that. Try removing max-width property and display as block; I've updated the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ajay,
It cuts down the image, added the output to the questions

Comment: Have you tried <img src="medical.jpg" width="100%">? Also try <img src="medical.jpg" style="display:block; width: 100%;" /> if that doesn't work. Outlook email is known for poor css rendering.

Comment: I think I got your question wrong. You want it to look like gmail? Then you can directly edit the image to that size and use it without height, so the text will be clear. Email css does not have advanced css3 inline properties.

Comment: Also try the updated answer. Refer https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ for properties that work in each browser.

Comment: Not the best of you are making a scalable email. If the image proportion changes then you have to keep changing the code to fix things.